# Joining query in Linq

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables. `ProductOrder` and `Member`.

```
ProductOrder: OrderId, MemberId, DateTimeUTC.
Member : MemberId, FName, LName.
```

I want to retun a list which content OrderId, Fname, LName, DateTimeUTC.

```
 public List<ProductOrder> GetOrderDetails()
        {
            using (var db = new StoreEntities())
            {
                             var query = (from pd in db.ProductOrder
                             join od in db.Member on pd.MemberId equals od.MemberId
                             orderby od.MemberId
                             select new
                             {
                                 pd.OrderId,
                                 od.FName,
                                 od.LName,
                                 pd.DateTimeUTC,
                             }).ToList();
                return query;
            }

        }
```

But here some error occur. [image]

Please help.

Comment: your return list (query) is not of type `ProductOrder`. It needs to `return public List<YourNewObjectHere> GetOrderDetails()`

Comment: Your ProductOrder model is not matching with the query result. Make sure the query result is matching with the ProductOrder model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns a collection of [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) instances. It shouldn't be returned from as method.

> **You cannot declare** a field, a property, an event, or **the return type of a method as having an anonymous type**.
>
> *from [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)*

Instead, you have to create new class to store your results:

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeUTC { get; set; }
}
```

change method declaration to return collection of `OrderInfo`:

```
public List<OrderInfo> GetOrderDetails()
```

and modify query to return a collection of these objects:

```
var query = (from pd in db.ProductOrder
             join od in db.Member on pd.MemberId equals od.MemberId
             orderby od.MemberId
             select new OrderInfo
             {
                 pd.OrderId,
                 od.FName,
                 od.LName,
                 pd.DateTimeUTC,
             }).ToList();
```